# linear programming on cypher analysis

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to solve my problem using linear programming (LP), I am trying to create simplex schema representation of this problem, I got 26 different variables `Xi(X1,X2,...,X26)`.

I can write down what I need in terms like this:

1. `X9+X10+...+X18 <= Xk where k={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` (while i need at
   least one k for which this term is valid)
2. `X19+X20+...+X26 <= Xk where k={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` (while i need at least one k for which this term is valid)

Each X represent frequency of character from any language for example:

```
X1 = 'e' frequency of E in english language is 12.7%
x9=b 1.5
x10=c 2.7
x11=j 0.1
x12=k 0.7
x13=m 2.4
x14=p 1.9
x15=q 0.09
x16=v 0.9
x17=x 0.15
x18=y 1.9
```

So:

```
X1 = 12.7 ; x9+...+x18 = 12.34
X1> x9+...+x18
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit as to what you are looking for? If you can give a small example where you are having the difficulty, that would help the people here answer. Thanks.

Comment: I am looking how to regurarly write it down, I need only common formulation, and I never did anything using LP nor the simplex schema which I want to assign to my cryptographic program.

Comment: Okay. You have started on the right note. You have identified your decision variables, X1...X26. Please edit your question to write down your constraints in English, and mention which constants are already known to you. What are you trying to minimize or maximize?

Comment: it is straddles checkerboard cypher, in this cypher chosen numbers of rows, has high frequency because every character is encoded like <RowNumber><CharacterPosition> ( for example row number is 2 than 10 characters in row will encode to 20,21,22,...,29) and because  10 characters in second row, and 8 characters in third row starts with one number, this number has high frequency in encoded text(numeric). My goal is to maximize frequency in first row or minimize frequency in second and third row so, that 2 numbers with highest frequency in the encoded text wont be numbers of rows.

Comment: I am afraid you have to explain the problem more. Please edit the question. Take a few lines to explain the problem, what does the cherckboard cypher look like, what is the problem you are trying to solve? Only if you explain can people help you.

Comment: this is checkerboard cypher http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/straddle-checkerboard-cipher/